# How to read/write to variables that persist and are updated between compiles?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on adding DLL hotloading to a C++ app. Because of this, I open 2 instances of MSVC: 1 instance runs the app while I code and compile on the other instance. Breakpoints are hit on the first instance, and I can continue to code on the 2nd instance without stopping the app.

To support this, I need to read and write to a (semi) persistent CMake variable between builds. I use that variable to decide how to name the generated files. That is, every time I compile some hot loadable DLL, I need to cycle between names to give the files being generated, because the previous files are in use by running app.

So, the generated files would cycle as:

1. path/to/some.a.pdb
2. path/to/some.b.pdb

How can I read/write to a variable every build/compile, which remembers the value from the previous compile. The CMakeCache doesn't work for this, because it gets set during the configure phase and not updated during the generation phase. Maybe it could be done with Generator Expressions.

Comment: I do not understand at all what is going on, but with `add_custom_command` you can literally run custom command. So write a python script, that reads state a file, copies the `pdb` file to new name and updates state, and saves the state to a file, and add it to `add_custom_command`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX`. Yes, you need to reconfigure, but it won't run into problems with writing to open/mapped libraries.

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html)

> Default filename postfix for libraries under configuration `<CONFIG>`.
>
> When a non-executable target is created its `<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` target property is initialized with the value of this variable if it is set.

and this piece of [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CONFIG_POSTFIX.html):

> Postfix to append to the target file name for configuration .
>
> When building with configuration `<CONFIG>` the value of this property is appended to the target file name built on disk. For non-executable targets, this property is initialized by the value of the variable `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` if it is set when a target is created. This property is ignored on the Mac for Frameworks and App Bundles.

You can cycle between different postfixes like so:

```
$ cmake -B build -DCMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX=_a
$ cmake --build build/ --config Release --target MySwappableDll
... start your app, which loads the _a libraries ...
... later, when you want to rebuild and swap out to _b, just reconfigure ...
$ cmake -B build -DCMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX=_b
$ cmake --build build/ --config Release --target MySwappableDll
... now the _b targets are incrementally built and you can hot swap ...
```

You can also use `RelWithDebInfo` or `Debug` or even a totally custom config (you could even create an "A" and a "B" config with different postfixes so you wouldn't need to re-run the configure step).

Comment: Thanks for the details response. I was hoping to find a way to do it without having to re-run the configure step each time, and instead do it at the generation step so I could just continuously hit build from the IDE.

Comment: It's kind of a footnote in my answer, but if you use a multi-config generator, you can define  custom configurations to avoid reconfiguring.

Comment: Admittedly, that removes the reconfigure step. Though, to cycle between names, one still has to cycle between selected configurations. Ideally, the renaming of the output files happen without having to mess with configuration settings. That is, just hit rebuild each time, and the correct filename is geneated, which cycles between the .a and .b versions.

Comment: You could use a custom target that calls a script that recursively calls `${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target MySwappableDll --config ${CONFIG}` and stores its state in a file. It would be responsible for flipping `CONFIG` back and forth. Seems pretty easy to get out of sync with any such scheme, though.

Comment: That's a thought.

Comment: Could maybe make it more robust by comparing the timestamps of each variant and building the older one.

Comment: I'm going to rethink what I'm trying to do and come up with a different way to accomplish it. Maybe it's difficult because I'm trying to go over the limits of CMake.

Comment: @Dess - that's probably the right idea.